# Running CMake from CreateProcess returns FileTracker FTK0001 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, cmake

After updating my windows 10 to 1903, executing the following cmake command using CreateProcess:

command: `cmd /C "cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="D:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"" ..`

code: `CreateProcess("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", command, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, 0, workingDir, &si, &pi))`

fails to find the compiler:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.18362.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

but succeeds (finds the correct MSVC compiler) when the exact same command is executed directly from the command prompt.

After digging through the trace, I found out that `CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake` fails when compiling `CompilerIdC.vcxproj` with the following:

```
  ClCompile:

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe /c /I"D:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include" /nologo /W0 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TC /FC /errorReport:queue CMakeCCompilerId.c

  FileTracker : error FTK0001: could not attach tracking.  The storage
  control block address is invalid.
  [D:\[path redacted]\CMakeFiles\3.12.2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]
```

this is the only error, all trace output before this, including versions and paths, are exactly the same as when successfully compiled from the command line.

How do I fix this error, or is this a problem with CreateProcess?
(This code works with no problems on Windows 10 1803 with the exact same compilers)

Comment: Can you create a simple win32 application without running CMake to see if you can target SDK version 18362 successfully?

Comment: I found the answer. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: the [Child Process Debugging](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool) extension produces this problem after the update. Disabling this extension fixes the problem.